# How can I prove this equation is solvable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given any integers $a, b, c$ and any prime $p$ not a divisor of $ab$,

show that $ax^2+by^2=c  \mod p$ is solvable...

I think this is combinatorial number theory.. but i don't know what to do..

Answer (score 1):

We have the equation $y^2=f(x)$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, for a quadratic polynomial $f$, since $ab\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Assume first that $p>2$. Over  $\mathbb{F}_p$ the quadratic polynomial $f$ attaines $(p+1)/2$ different values. Since there are exactly $(p-1)/2$ non-squares in $\mathbb{F}_p$, at least one value of $f$ must be a square, say $f(r)=s^2$. But then $(r,s)$ is a solution. Now assume that $p=2$. Plugging in $x=0$, $x=1$ etc. it is easy to see that there is a solution, too (the only conic without a "solution", i.e., an affine point over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $y^2=x^2+x+y+1$).